# WordPress paginate_links() function doesn't generate properly links after apply filters

Tags: pagination

I'm a junior WordPress developer. Apologies in advance for mistakes that prove foolish.

I have an issue with my archive movie. Movie it is a custom post type.

paginate_links() function works fine without apply filter but after apply it the function generate wrongs links.

For example, after filtering if I go to page 2, the url will be: http://mydomain/peliculas/page/2/?genero%5B0%5D=ficcion&inicio=1950&final=2018&duracion=todos#038;genero%5B1%5D=documental&genero%5B2%5D=animacion&inicio=1950&final=2018&duracion=todos

If you note, the generated url concatenate the substring '&inicio=1950&final=2018&duracion=todos#038;' in the middle of querystring. This substring it is a part of page 1 URL.

This issue happens when I navigate between pages and filters were apply it.

I really appreciate your sugestions to resolve this issue.